# Weird date result adding 1 month to a given date

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using following piece of code to get next week date from a given date at 12:00am:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:0];
NSDate *todayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


int daysToAdd = 7;
NSDate *tomorrowDate = [todayDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];


NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tomorrowDate];
todoItemDueDateText.text = stringDate;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
NSString *fechasimulada = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrowDate];
dateFieldSimulatedText.text = fechasimulada;
```

If I log the result date, it is working fine.

Now, a similar piece of code to get next month date from a given date at 12:00am:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:0];
NSDate *todayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


//NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[dateComponents setMonth:1];
//NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* tomorrowDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:todayDate options:0];


NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tomorrowDate];
todoItemDueDateText.text = stringDate;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY"];
NSString *fechasimulada = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrowDate];
```

I don't know why, but the second piece of code gives the expected date but -1 hour.

UPDATE:

I will show you the dates:

Source date (today at 12:00am)+7 h

[image]

Next week date from previous given date:

[image]

Next month date from previous given date:

[image]

Comment: What are the dates?  Are you crossing DST?

Comment: I will put the logs in my question. Thank you @nhgrif.

Comment: I actually don't think `NSDate` cares about DST, so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: @nhgrif, you can now see the logs in my edited question.

Comment: May be iOS is taking into account that on 9th march starts Daylight saving time?

Comment: Then you were right about crossing DST. please put your comment in an answer to select it . Thank you again...

Comment: @nhgrif -- I always spring back and fall forward.

Comment: @nhgrif, would you mind putting your first comment in to an answer, I would be glad markint it as correct answer to my question.

Comment: Have you tested to be sure this is the reason?  Have you added 1 month across a time period that doesn't include DST?

Comment: @nhgrif, Yes, I have it tested adding 1 month to 2065-11-12 07:00, the result is 2065-12-12 07:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` takes Daylight Savings into account.  If you cross a DST day, you'll experience this issue.